# Nextcloud installation

Tags: software-installation

I'm new in this forum , I expect to install the software nextcloud into my computer.
I read many many topic on this installation but never once works well at the end.
Did you have some tuto where you have already test and work well ? please

Thks in advance guys for your support,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me [How to install the Nextcloud Client on Ubuntu](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-the-nextcloud-client-on-ubuntu/)